# Android Hardware (mobile )

Tags: java, android

i want to connect Sony Ericsson xperia x10 (android mobile) to the eclipse (emulator)
i was able to connect htc mobile to the eclipse.but i could not connect the sony mobile to the eclipse.can you please help me?

Comment: Have you installed the drivers?

Comment: you need to install the adb drivers for the Sony Ericsson device. I hope you meant that you are not able to detect the device on ddms.

Comment: eclipse is not the emulator, "eclipse" installs applications either on an emulator or on a physical device. You'll never connect the emulator to a physical device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect the xperia x10 with an USB cable, enable the connection on the mobile and switch on debug mode on the mobile (you'll find the switch somewhere in the settings - can't give more details right now, MobileOutOfReachError on my side ;) ).

This was all I had to do - just started the application on eclipse and the app was installed and executed on the real phone.

Wait - I installed the PC companion. If the above steps don't work, then maybe this is necessary too.

Comment: thanks Andreas_D ,i install the PC companion,the ddms can detect it know